# Canadian visit visa processing time and procedure : Indian citizen applying from Israel

Tags: visas, canada

I am traveling to a conference in Canada on 18th June. I am currently a postdoc in Israel on A/2 student visa and I am an Indian citizen. I applied for Canadian visit visa online from Israel on 23rd May. The application is still under process and since there is only one week left I was wondering if someone know what are the next steps involved ? Do I get my visa stamped at the Canadian embassy in Tel Aviv or do I have to mail my passport somewhere to get it stamped ? If so can I expedite this mailing process (like using UPS Worldwide expedited delivery)?

Comment: Why don't you ask the embassy?

Comment: Have you gone into the [online account](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=029&top=3) and checked the status and for messages?

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk I asked, but since it is apparently processed by an external agency they don't know.

Comment: @Dorothy I checked the online status, it says it is under review. I am more interested in knowing what happens next ? Does my visa get stamped here in Israel or do I have to mail it ?

Comment: @SajinKoroth you'll almost certainly receive the passport with your visa ready if you're approved.

Comment: Keep checking for messages; you should be advised what to do next. Do you still have your passport in hand? First [use this form](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/contacts/web-form.asp) to enquire, then consider contacting [Consular Services](http://www.canadainternational.gc.ca/israel/contact-contactez.aspx?lang=eng)

Comment: People are voting to close this as primarily opinion-based. Why? The specific questions asked are all purely factual. This isn't the typical "OMG my visa's slow and I'm panicky, will I get it in time?" question: it asks concrete questions about what actions the asker will be required to take if their visa is granted.

Comment: I just wanted to update here that I got the visa on time. The embassy in Tel-Aviv was very helpful. A million thanks to them. The decision was made in Ankara embassy but the decision is reflected on the online system and the embassy in Tel-Aviv printed the visa. The embassy in Ankara was also helpful over the email but they couldn't expedite my application. The embassy in Tel-Aviv got to know the decision even before it was reflected on my online profile.

Comment: Forgot to include the date on which I received the VISA. It was on 13th June 2017.